# Update UITableView when related NSManagedObject is updated

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have following relationship hierarchy between core-data entities (managed objects):

> Entity1 > Entity2 > Entity3

There's a one-to-one relationship between `Entity1` and `Entity2`, and one-to-many relationship between `Entity2` and `Entity3`.

I have a view controller that displays a list of `Entity1` records, using `NSFetchedResultsController`. The `UITableViewCell` shows information from `Entity1`, `Entity2` and `Entity3`. Now, the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are automatically called when `Entity1` object is added/updated/deleted, BUT when the related `Entity2` or `Entity3` records are added/updated/deleted, the delegate methods are not called.

In this situation, what's the best or possible way to recognize that related records have been updated, and that `UITableViewCell` needs to be updated as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make dirty the properties of the other entities. In other words, you should call

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"someProperty"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"someProperty"];
```

on the entities you want to update.

Here a sample solution that makes possible what you want to achieve.

[NSFetchedResultsController pitfall](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=825)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is a nice trick. - Instead of overriding the accessor methods of the related entity (as suggested in the link), one could also listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`, and if an "Entity2" or "Entity3" object has changed, mark the related "Entity1" object as dirty. - Another idea: Add a transient "dummy" attribute to "Entity1". To mark an object as dirty, you only have to assign a value to the dummy attribute.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the other suggestions. ;)

Comment: willChange/DidChange apparently does not work (anymore), and neither does setting a value to nil and then back to the real value ... The trick that did it for me was introducing a transient "dirty" attribute and setting that to a timestamp.